# Possible to give built app (not source) to 3rd party for them to sign and submit?

Tags: xcode, app-store

My company is developing an app on behalf of another company who will themselves be submitting it to the app store.

While under development the app is being signed using my companies dev certificates, however for submission to the app store it will be signed with their certificates.

My question is is it possible to deliver them the app as a binary which they can then sign?

Its not possible to build or create an archive in XCode if the app has no code-signing/provisioning profiles therefore how can the app be delivered to the other company without giving them the XCode project and all the source code?